RDP-session will be closed when on the remote computer the same user logs in locally - how to prevent
Two PC's running windows 11 pro.
One of them is placed in the office, the other one is placed at home.
Using RDP I log in into the Office-PC from home.
Now there are two kinds of behavior:

No user is logged in the office-PC, I'll be logged in using RDP. That's fine
If another user than I'm trying to log in is already logged in, I get a warning, that another user is logged in. That's also fine

But when I'm trying to log in with user PETER using RDP in the office-PC while this user PETER already is logged in on the office-pc no warning came up and the RDP session is closed immediately!!!
Is there any possibility that the user, who wants to log in using RDP, receives a warning message that the same user is already activ and he's asked if he want to close this session
